# Como publicar um projeto ASP.NET (.NET Framework) sem a dependência do iis

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis

Tenho um projeto funcionando mas com a dependência do IIS.

Em algumas pesquisas encontrei a possibilidade de tornar o projeto self host.
Conforme no link: http://www.macoratti.net/18/05/net_conc3.htm

Mas exemplos apontam apenas para projetos do tipo Console App (.NET Framework).
No qual em uma das etapas é adicionar um trecho de código no método Main() da classe Program
Porém em projeto do tipo Aplicativo Web ASP.NET (.NET Framework) não tem essa classe.

Como proceder nesse caso? ou não é possível publicar um Aplicativo Web ASP.NET (.NET Framework) sem a dependência do IIS?

Comment: Como assim sem dependência?

Comment: Para publicar um Aplicativo Web ASP.NET (.NET Framework)  é preciso fazer a publicação através do IIS. Uma aplicação semelhante porém em (.NET Core) é possível fazer a publicação em modo self host, por exemplo: se fizer uma publicação para pasta. um exe é criado e ao executa-lo um serviço de hospedagem é criado permitindo o funcionamento da aplicação web sem a necessidade do IIS. Se analisar o link que eu mencionei Verá uma alternativa para (.Net Framework) porem somente para projetos do tipo Console App, meu caso é Aplicativo Web ASP.NET

Comment: A única forma de criar uma aplicação web self-hosted é sendo um executável (por isso o exemplo mostra como um console app). De forma bem básica: se não for um executável, não tem como você fazer rodar...

Comment: Seguindo os passos do tutorial que você apresentou, vai acabar com um `ConsoleApp` que vai fazer o papel de host da sua aplicação, assim como o IIS faria. Acho válido você explicar porque não quer utilizar o IIS, quais as restrições do seu ambiente e benefícios que você espera dessa abordagem?

Comment: Outra opção, se você não quer um console. Você pode seguir a mesma receita, porém implementar em Windows Service